# Issue with property setter with an object and toolbox

Tags: c#

This code works fine, I can check if a timecode is valid when the
property changes its value. But the problem is that I cannot set the
value of this property in the toolbox, because of the `new ValidTimeCodeEventArgs`.

Is there a way to fix this so I could
change the value in the toolbox and check if it is correct?

```
[Browsable(true)]
public event EventHandler<ValidTimeCodeEventArgs> ValidTimeCode;

private string strTimeCode;
[Category("Custom")]
[Browsable(true)]
[DefaultValue(typeof(string), "00:00:00:00")]
public string StrTimeCode {
    get {
        return strTimeCode;
    }
    set {

        if (value != null) {
            ValidTimeCode(this, new ValidTimeCodeEventArgs(IsValidTimeCode(value, FrameRate, IsDropFrame)));
            strTimeCode = value;
            initValue = strTimeCode;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ValidTimeCodeEventArgs : EventArgs {

    public ValidTimeCodeEventArgs(bool isValid) {
        IsValid = isValid;
    }

    public bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what "I cannot set the value of this property in the toolbox, because of the `new ValidTimeCodeEventArgs`" means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The code is part of a usercontrol. After add the control to a form, when I try to set the initial value of StrTimeCode to "00:00:00:00" for example, Visual Studio generates this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." If I comment the line "ValidTimeCode(this, new ValidTimeCodeEventArgs(IsValidTimeCode(value, FrameRate, IsDropFrame)));" the program compiles with no errors. I think the problem is at the time of create an instance of the object ValidTimeCodeEventArgs.

Comment: I see, `ValidTimeCode` is an event and you're raising the event in an unsafe way, you don't check if anyone is subscribed

Answer (score 0):

Your `ValidTimeCode` event probably doesn't have any subscribers when you try to  raise it. Try:

```
ValidTimeCode?.Invoke(this, new ValidTimeCodeEventArgs(IsValidTimeCode(value, FrameRate, IsDropFrame)));
```

This basically does a null check on the handler (it's null if no one subscribed to the event), then only raises it if it isn't null. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) for more info.

Comment: It works fine now.

Comment: Thanls a lot. Regards.